# How can I SELECT top 500 rows from table1 and INSERT them to table2?

Tags: sql, t-sql, insert

I have completely same defined 2 tables : t2 and t1.

t2 has 1000 rows and t1 is totally empty.

How can I SELECT top 500 rows from t2 and INSERT them to t1?

Comment: Why do you want to select the TOP 500 rows from a totally empty table ??? You say *t1 is totally empty* and then *how can I select top 500 rows from t1* - doesn't really make any sense at all....

Comment: Thanks for spotting it; I have fixed the question text

Comment: Also: as gbn rightfully points out: without an `ORDER BY`, your `TOP 500` gives you an arbitrary 500 rows... so you want the `TOP 500` rows order by **what** criteria??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'll use "emptyTable" and "populatedTable" because the questions is confusing

**Important** `TOP` without an ORDER BY gives 500 arbitrary rows. There is never an implied or natural order to a table

```
INSERT INTO emptyTable
SELECT TOP 500 * 
FROM populatedTable
ORDER BY What -- need this to define TOP 500
```

The lack of column list here is usually defined as bad practice but works only if

- the tables are identical
- there is no IDENTITY column in emptyTable

Edit:

ORDER BY is *required* to guarantee row order. See these. It's also in the ANSI standard

- http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx

Comment: +1 good point with the `ORDER BY` - `TOP (x)` without `ORDER BY` gives just random rows...

Comment: As I understood it, Without joins, the query optimiser will go with the physical order (i.e. the order of the clustered index, where present)

Comment: @RowlandShaw: There is a coincidence that appears this way, but don't ever rely on it

Comment: @RowlandShaw: found links. The 2nd guy works on the SQL Server codebase at MS

Comment: @gbn those show the case for where a filtering clause has applied (so where I said "without joins", I probably should've said "without any filters such as joins or where clauses").

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO t1
SELECT TOP 500 * FROM t2
```

You select the top 500, and insert them.

Comment: Actually, @marc_s, he says that t1 is empty, so I'd assume that he wants them to go there. Also: yes, I forgot the `*`

Comment: @marc_s Not so sure, as they also said that t1 had no rows (so there aren't a first 500)

Answer (score 3):

```
insert t2(fieldslist)
select top 500 fieldslist from t1
```

Answer (score 2):

If both tables have the same schema, it's as simple as:

```
INSERT INTO t1
SELECT TOP 500 * 
FROM t2
```

Comment: @marc_s As I understood it, Without joins, the query optimiser will go with the physical order (i.e. the order of the clustered index, where present)

Comment: No - that *might* be the case now and then - but without `ORDER BY`, there is **NO** guarantee whatsoever about what order will be used - it's not deterministic - there is **no natural ORDER** in SQL Server

Comment: Doesn't work unless you provide an identity column my error says